# hover on repeat and click on menu protractor

Tags: angularjs, hover, click, protractor, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new with protractor and I am facing some issues with mouse events. I am trying to hover over one of the ng-repeat items and then click on one of the menu options that they appear on top of each one of them on mouse over.
What I tried to do is:

```
var list-element= element.all(by.repeater('element in list'));
list-element.getText().then(function (value) {
            browser.actions().mouseMove(value[0]).perform();
}); 

element.all(by.css('i.icon.x.blue')).then(function(menu-item) {  `
            element(menu-item[0]).click();
});
```

seems like hovering is not recognized and the element to click on cannot be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be using `getText()`.

From what I understand, you should be using something like this:

```
var list-element = element.all(by.repeater('element in list')).first();

browser.actions().mouseMove(list-element).perform();
list-element.all(by.css('i.icon.x.blue')).first();
```